# Can you use an Ubuntu Live CD to fix windows FAT32 problems?

Tags: windows, live-cd

Assuming your boss has a Windows Machine, and it would be really bad for your career if his personal computer didn't work anymore.

Can you use a Ubuntu Live CD to load Disk Utilities or fdsk or simular to check his FAT32 partition for errors.

His computer is booting, doing a diskcheck and crashing (rebooting).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what the specific problem(s) might be, but try this:

```
sudo apt-get install dosfstools
```

This will give you something like the standard disk checking utils for Linux that (as the manpage claims) work on FAT16/32 partitions.  Once installed you can get some info on them via:

```
man dosfsck
```

I've never used these myself so I don't know how effective or comprehensive they are, but if an Ubuntu Live CD is going to be of any use, I'd start there.

If the data on the disk in question is *very* valuable - ie lots of money could be lost if it dies - then you may want to find a data recovery specialist.

Good luck!

Comment: Awesome, thanks heaps for the advise. I'm heading out to his place tomorrow to see what I can do.

Comment: If you found my reply useful, you should upvote it so it will show up near the top for other people searching for the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

Hell yes! you can wipe the hard drive and install Linux!  :)
My guess is that you are running Windows 95,98,98se,or me , right?
Just live boot , back up your files and reinstall.
If you are using xp,vista,or 7 - Use NTFS

Comment: I was hoping for something less destructive or time comsuming. Remember this is my Boss's computer who is middle management at a major bank. I just want to go in there, run some scans and get out hopefully. Trashing is computer could be really bad for my career. As for his windows version. I'm not certain, he wouldn't have a clue. But I assume it's 98SE or ME. Otherwise I have NO idea why he'd be using FAT32.